# delete millions for records from table between date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table with name of `camera_activities`, and there are more than millions of records in that, the table structure is like

```
CREATE TABLE camera_activities
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  camera_id integer NOT NULL,
  access_token_id integer,
  action text NOT NULL,
  done_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  ip inet,
  extra json,
  camera_exid text,
  name text
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE camera_activities
  OWNER TO 8hhjhjgghg7;

-- Index: camera_activities_camera_id_done_at_index

-- DROP INDEX camera_activities_camera_id_done_at_index;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX camera_activities_camera_id_done_at_index
  ON camera_activities
  USING btree
  (camera_id, done_at);
```

and a single record is like

[image: record]

Here is the problem,

I want to delete all the records before 2016 and they are going to be so many ones, the range is between 2014 and so on, we started adding data on 2014..

I have tried a simple query and it works well, for example, If I delete between 2 dates as

```
delete from camera_activities where done_at>'2017-07-12 10:55:37+00' and done_at<='2017-07-13 09:23:00+00
```

This works but its a lot of time-consuming, there more than millions of records, is there any fast way to do this job?

NOTE: If I may increase the date range to a month or more than a month, The query just continues running and never came back with any result.

Any help or guidance will be helpful,

Comment: About how many values are you wanting to save? So I guess about how many values after 2016 do you have?

Comment: You can create new table, copy everything you need from existing table, then delete the old one.

Comment: I was going to suggest what fen1x said, you'd `truncate` the old table which is much faster than `delete`, but this only makes sense if you have less data to keep than delete

Comment: It should do `seqscan` so I don't think it makes much difference if he has more or less data to keep as it will go thru whole table anyway and marking tuple as deleted seems faster than making copy of lets say 30% of its contents. It would make in practice `vacuum full` so I suppose there is time saving here, but I think he should partition this table for future time savings anyway.

Comment: I just want a little demo with a query to start with something. at the moment i only have sentences that how is that possible

Comment: I see I can save all the values to some table, but how? for example i want to save values from today to the past year (just last 12 months) and delete all other things?

Comment: If you just want to delete some records (as in your example, two dates 
 concerning 2017) and index on done_at only could help.  In fact, your index (camera_id, done_at) would be scanned and not seeked.  As general strategy consider partitioning by date.

Comment: Does that table need to be available for inserts at all time or can you go into "maintenance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to do massive DELETE operations.

1) Create another table, drop old one and rename the new one, and `ANALYZE` the new table in the end:

```
begin;
create table camera_activities_new (like camera_activities including all);

insert into camera_activities_new
select * from camera_activities
where done_at >= ''2016-01-01'::date;

alter sequence camera_activities_id_seq owned by camera_activities_new;
drop table camera_activities;
alter table camera_activities_new rename to camera_activities;
alter index camera_activities_new_camera_id_done_at_idx rename to camera_activities_camera_id_done_at_idx;
commit;

analyze camera_activities;
```

This approach guarantees that the resulting table will be in the best shape (no bloating). But it can be less convenient your system is heavy loaded and the table is involved. In such cases, "smooth deletion" might look better.

2) "Smooth" deletion: delete only relatively small amount of rows each time, use more aggressive autovacuum settings and control bloating.

Example, showing how to split deletion to many independent transactions (in bash; relies on `$PGDATABASE`, `$PGHOST`, `$PGUSER`, `$PGPASSWORD` environment variables):

```
while true; do
  res=$(psql -c "delete from camera_activities where id in (select id camera_activities where done_at < '2016-01-01'::date limit 500);" \
    | grep DELETE | awk {'print $2'} )
  if [[ $res = '0' ]]; then break; fi;
  sleep 0.3; # control speed here; check bloating level
done
```

– this will stop automatically when no rows are left to delete.

Your index on `(camera_id, done_at)` should speed up subselect, making Bitmap Index Scan – check with `EXPLAIN`.  But probably it's worth to have a separate index on `done_at`, it can be `btree` or `brin` (lossy but smaller in size) in this case:

```
create i_camera_activities_done_at on camera_activities using brin(done_at);
```

Example of "more aggressive" (than default) autovacuum settings:

```
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.01
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.05
autovacuum_naptime = 60
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20
```

Different queries which help to see your table's bloating level:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat
- http://blog.ioguix.net/postgresql/2014/09/10/Bloat-estimation-for-tables.html
- https://github.com/ioguix/pgsql-bloat-estimation/blob/master/table/table_bloat-82-84.sql
- https://github.com/dataegret/pg-utils/blob/master/sql/table_bloat.sql (and for indexes:
- https://github.com/dataegret/pg-utils/blob/master/sql/index_bloat.sql; these queries require pgstattuple extension)

Comment: what a brilliant answer it is.

Comment: Hi , I just got an error on that
`ERROR:  cannot drop table camera_activities because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  default for table camera_activities_new column id depends on sequence camera_activities_id_seq
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.`

Comment: Do `alter sequence camera_activities_id_seq owned by camera_activities_new;` before `drop ...`. Sorry forgot about the sequence.

Comment: Edited the answer.